# Issue comparing structs in C

Tags: c, struct, codewarrior

I have created the following embedded C code using codewarrior. I have modified it and cut alot out to post this example. Three files:

Main.c:

```
#include <NormalState.h>
#include <Temperatures.h>

struct Temp *currentTemp = createTemp();
struct Temp *minTemp = createTemp();
struct Temp *maxTemp = createTemp();
minTemp->fehrenheit = 68;
maxTemp->fehrenheit = 72;
currentTemp->fehrenheit = 70;
int i = 0;
buffer = 3;

for(;;)
{
    runNormalState();
    if(i > 10000)
    {
        if(heat == FALSE)
        {
            currentTemp->fehrenheit--;
        }
        else
        {
            currentTemp->fehrenheit++;
        }

        i = 0;
    }
    i++;
}
```

Temperatures.h:

```
struct Temp{
    float celcius;
    float fehrenheit;
    float kelvin;
};

struct Temp *createTemp()
{
    return malloc(sizeof(struct Temp));
}
```

NormalState.h:

```
#include <Temperatures.h>

byte buffer;
bool heat, cool;

void runNormalState()
{
    if(currentTemp->fehrenheit <= minTemp->fehrenheit - buffer)
    {
        heat = TRUE;
    }
    else if(currentTemp->fehrenheit >= maxTemp->fehrenheit + buffer)
    {
        cool = TRUE;
    }
}
```

I wrote some tests that start `currentTemp->fehrenheit` at 70 and deincrements it approximately every second. The if/else statement in NormalState.h checks if the heat needs to be turned on.

`buffer` is 3. `MinTemp->fehrenheit - buffer` is 65. So when `currentTemp->fehrenheit` drops below 65, heat should equal TRUE. However, the value never changes. Likewise, if I remove `buffer` from `minTemp->fehrenheit - buffer` from the if/else statement, so that it is just `minTemp->fehrenheit`, heat is always evaluated to TRUE.

I cannot for the life of me figure out what is going on here. I can say what I have discovered already through tests:

- The if/else statement is NOT being skipped over. It is just not being evaluated.
- I have checked the values of both `currentTemp->fehrenheit` and `minTemp->fehrenheit`. They both equal what I would expect each respective value to be at that given time.
- It is not related to the struct data members being floats. I have the same issue if I made the data members of `Temp` ints, bytes, doubles, or floats.

I have a feeling this is related to some kind of fundamental misunderstanding I may have with pointers or conversions. I could also be missing something incredibly basic, but I don't know where else to turn. The other engineer here couldn't figure it out either.

Comment: The name is normally Fahrenheit with an 'a', and Celsius has an 's' in the middle.  That is tangential to your other problems.

Comment: Please show us more code, in the form of an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) or
SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)).  We can't tell what is going wrong from the limited context you've given us.  You can help yourself by adding `printf()` statements for the control variables, too.

Comment: I suspect you are probably changing the values in a function and you a passing the struct as an argument rather than a pointer to a struct. If you are, your changes are never preserved outside the function.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: except that `heat` is a plain variable, I'm inclined to agree...

Comment: Sorry for the bad example, Im putting together a better code snippet and will update shortly.

Comment: Another tangential comment, but is this struct really necessary anyway? Couldn't you just store the temperature in Celsius and use that everywhere in your code? You only need to do the conversions to and from Fahrenheit and Kelvin when inputting or outputting data. There's no need to keep an internal representation of all three values.

Comment: @squeamishossifrage I dont disagree. Im just an intern following orders. I was told to do it this way.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I added relevant code. The code is running on a development board. So I am printing the values of the variables to putty through a COM port. The if/else statement I was referring to is in NormalState.h

Comment: You set `heat = TRUE` and `cool = TRUE`, but nowhere do you set `heat = FALSE` and `cool = FALSE`. So eventually, both will be true and will be true forever.

Comment: @user3386109 That's not the case. That's done in the full code as well. I forgot to stick it in this example, though.

Comment: If you change `cool = TRUE;` to `heat = FALSE;`  temperature will start to change. And set smaller value for `if(i > 10000)` to see it.

Comment: @mstagg Fair enough, but we can only help you fix the code that you post.

Comment: Having the function defined in the header file without the `inline` or `static` keyword normally means that only one source file (translation unit or TU) in the program can include that header. Are you sure that you've done that (once in `Temperatures.h` and once in `NormalState.h`)? Also, as a general rule, headers you write go in double quotes; headers provided by 'the system' go in angle brackets (`<stdio.h>`, etc). Also, also: your initialization for `struct Temp *currentTemp = createTemp();` and two other variables is using C++ initialization rules, not C initialization rules. What gives?

Comment: _[...Continuing...]_ But then I see that you also have other executable code shown that cannot appear outside a function, but it is not shown inside a function, so this isn't an MCVE, isn't it? We can't copy and paste the code you've shown and expect it to compile.  Please, pay attention to the advice you're given (like read up on an MCVE!).